# robots.txt Not Updating

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

Today I received an email from Webmaster Tools stating that "Googlebot cannot access CSS and JS files". So I set about updating my robots.txt file located in the root of my server.

Original Contents:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-content/themes/ #<--CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM

Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemapindex.xml
```

I removed the line "Disallow: /wp-content/themes/" from the file and re-uploaded the file but when I viewed the new file in my browser, nothing had changed I then did the following:

1. Deleted the .txt file from the root
2. Cleared cache (W3 Total Cache)

But still robots.txt was viewable in my browser. This could only mean one thing, that the file was being virtually generated right? I even viewed in a different browser to ensure no caching was taking place.

After much searching I have found no answer as to why my robots.txt won't update or where it is being generated from?

Does anyone here have any ideas as to whats going on?

Some plugins I use:

1. Better WordPress Google XML Sitemaps
2. W3 Total Cache
3. Yoast SEO

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What webserver are you using? Nginx, for example, will cache static files.

Comment: Yeah I have Nginx running, but i've never seen it cache like this before. Any ideas on best practice to clear it?

Comment: You can try the Nginx Helper plugin or run `sudo service nginx reload`.

Comment: cheers for the help man but just realised I have Cloudflare enabled, cleared that cache and  worked a treat. Schoolboy error.

Comment: [Cross-post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/195923/34147)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se] and questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this in one of those two more appropriate places.

Answer (score 10):

After a few hours of head bashing trying to figure this one out, turns out I completely forgot I have Cloudflare enabled. A purge of that cache did the job.

Hopefully my few hours of pain have not been in vain and someone else with a similar issue is reminded that they have Cloudflare enabled by reading this!

Comment: I too have purged the cache and no luck. How did you do this in Cloudflare?

Answer (score 2):

The cache must be cleared in the cloudflare caching menu if you use cloudflare.
Otherwise, the cache will have to be cleared again depending on how long the browser cache has been used.

[image: Disable caching in cloudflare service]

Answer (score 0):

i haved the same problem 
when i updated my robots.txt it was revert to the same settings before and also when i deleted it it come back again as it seems it was virtual created from the website 
but after when i updated my wordpress it was started again working 
maybe try update wordpress

Comment: it seems that wordpress blcoks it because my wordpress was outdated and i did updated it to the latest version after my robots.txt was working again.
Now i can edit it again and it is not anymore reverted to the 
"
User-agent: *
Disallow:
"